# Dundas controls for SSRS 2005 installation on SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services

I have licensed dundas reporting controls for BIDS 2005. Recently we migrated SQL Server 2005 to 2008. Now when I am installing dundas reporting controls it is asking for VS2005. Please suggest me how to resolve this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Contact Dundas - they have different install packages for 2008. But they do not sell the product anymore, so you may be out of luck.